# GAM selection via EDF vs. adding penalties

Tags: r, regression, model-selection, regularization, generalized-additive-model

I have a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) I'm using for modelling fish counts and many covariates to test (with different proportions of NA's in each covariate), but not enough data to include them all in the same model at once. I'm aware of, but don't fully understand, the `select=TRUE` method and have also been taught to remove variables when the EDF is at or slightly below 1, and clearly not significant (or a parametric estimate is very close to zero). I'd like to know what are some things to keep in mind when removing variables in this way and how it differs from `select=TRUE`. Is the 2nd method OK if the sample size isn't large enough to accommodate more than a few covariates (in addition to random effects)?

My goal is to explain the data with the minimum number of predictor variables.

**EDIT:**

Select=FALSE:

```
mod <- bam(num ~ 
           
           CYR.std * Season +
             
           sed_depth * ave_hw +
           total_ave_ma +
           s(ave_tt) + 
             
           s(temp) +
           s(DO) +
           s(bottom_canopy) +
           
           # Structural components
           s(Site, bs = "re") +
           s(Site, fCYR, bs = "re") +
           s(Site, CYR.std, bs = "re") +
           s(Season, fCYR, bs = "re") +
           
           offset(log(area_sampled)), 

         data = toad, 
         
         method = 'fREML',
         # method = "ML",
         
         discrete = TRUE, # discretization only available with fREML
         
         select = FALSE,
         
         family = poisson,
         control = list(trace = TRUE))

> summary(mod)

Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
num ~ CYR.std * Season + sed_depth * ave_hw + total_ave_ma + 
    s(ave_tt) + s(temp) + s(DO) + s(bottom_canopy) + s(Site, 
    bs = "re") + s(Site, fCYR, bs = "re") + s(Site, CYR.std, 
    bs = "re") + s(Season, fCYR, bs = "re") + offset(log(area_sampled))

Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -4.6363582  1.3406977  -3.458 0.000544 ***
CYR.std            0.0233992  0.1144859   0.204 0.838053    
SeasonWET          0.9901602  1.5486474   0.639 0.522582    
sed_depth          0.0137553  0.0046723   2.944 0.003240 ** 
ave_hw             0.0331158  0.0149016   2.222 0.026263 *  
total_ave_ma       0.0222740  0.0062046   3.590 0.000331 ***
CYR.std:SeasonWET -0.0498692  0.1380378  -0.361 0.717896    
sed_depth:ave_hw  -0.0006050  0.0002818  -2.147 0.031788 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                     edf  Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
s(ave_tt)         1.9033   2.294  15.164 0.000946 ***
s(temp)           1.0000   1.000   0.010 0.922106    
s(DO)             2.1938   2.736   3.398 0.250328    
s(bottom_canopy)  1.0000   1.000   0.043 0.836254    
s(Site)           0.9325  47.000   1.355 0.506944    
s(fCYR,Site)     90.5698 511.000 347.037  < 2e-16 ***
s(CYR.std,Site)  21.0667  46.000 147.907 0.001109 ** 
s(Season,fCYR)   11.8387  16.000  90.683 0.000468 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.764   Deviance explained = 70.3%
fREML = 1132.4  Scale est. = 1         n = 856
```

Comment: When would EDF be zero? I think in most cases it is supposed to be at least 1 or higher unless youre doing something specific that makes the EDF that way

Comment: I do have a variable with an EDF <1, but this is just an aside as I'm mostly interested in the fixed effects. I have select=FALSE and one random effect has an EDF of 0.9325 (p-value=0.506944). That may just be because I have that variable included more than once and it maybe "hogging all the variability?" for that variable (it's include once as random intercept and again as a random slope). s(Site, bs = "re") + s(Site, CYR.std, bs = "re") <- location + location & continuous year.

Comment: It may be easier to assist if you include the important parts of your code and consequent output in the question, as it's otherwise difficult to ascertain why this is the case. Typically EDFs can be shrunk to below zero when `select=TRUE` (that is essentially the purpose of it anyway), but why your RE terms are this way is not totally clear unless more information is provided about how it was coded altogether.

Comment: Looking at the s(DO) term for example, if I did backwards elimination it would stay in the model because the EDF >1, but with select=True it be kicked out entirely.

Comment: Whoever told you to do feature-model selection that way (retain if EDF >= 1; drop if EDF < 1) is just plain wrong.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand EDF can be *very* close to 0 if the penalty on the null space allows the term to be effectively shrunk out of the model. These extra penalties are invoked with `select = TRUE` as described in the OPs original question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @GavinSimpson

Comment: Does anyone know of a good reference for why traditional stepwise elimination in regression is not preferable for GAMs?

Comment: @Nate stepwise elimination is not preferrable for any model perhaps with the exception of wanting to find purely the best predictive model (and even then I wouldn't do selection via p values or EDF)